# Why does get_pages return wrong data and not what I want?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a function that uses get_pages to build an array which is then converted to json.

Everything works correctly however the query is getting all posts under development instead of only child pages under the currently viewed development.

I've tried using WP_Query however that bugs out when run in the backend.

```
    function data_feed() {


    $i = 0;

    $map_builder = array();

    $args = array(
      'post_type'=> 'developments',
      'child_of' => $post->ID,
    );


    $the_query = get_pages($args);

    foreach ( $the_query as $post_f ) : setup_postdata( $post );


      if($i == 0){ $lat = 50; $long = 50;  } else { $lat = ''; $long = ''; }

      $map_builder[$i] = array(
      'title' => get_the_title($post->ID),
      'excerpt'    =>  get_the_excerpt($post->ID),
      'price' => '9999999',
      'status' => 'available',
      'coords' => array( 'lat' => $lat, 'long' => $long )


      );

      $i++;

    endforeach;

    wp_reset_postdata();


    $jqa = array('map-pin'=> $map_builder + array( 'canvas' => array( 'src' => 'http://localhost/acf-property-manager-app/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/the-avenues-site-plan-new.png', 'width'=> 1000, 'height' => 562 )));

    return json_encode( $jqa );


    }
```

Right now it returns all posts under developments.

What it should return is only the child posts of the currently viewed development.

Comment: `'child_of' => $post->ID,` - where is `$post` defined? Please look at what that variable is immediately before you're trying to use it.

Comment: Ah! $post->ID should be returning the ID of the page but it needed global $post; added.

Can't believe I missed that thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding :-

```
global $post;
```

Passes the correct ID to the query and results are now correct!